# Javascript New Operator

Tags: javascript

I'm new to OOP based JavaScript. For testing purpose I've created a following snippet. I've created four buttons, on clicking each button it will to different functions. When I click any of the buttons for the first time, it gives the predicted results. on the clicking any of the buttons for the second time, it gives me the following error:

```
classFunction = new classFunction();
```

The code which I've used is as below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var classFunction;

      function classFunction() {
        this.publicVariable = 'Public Varibale';
        var privateVariable = 'Private Variable';

        this.publicMethod = function () {
          alert('Public Method');
        }

        function privateMethod() {
          alert('private Method');
        }

        return this;
      }

      function privateVariable() {
        classFunction = new classFunction();
        alert(classFunction.privateVariable);
      }

      function publicvariable() {
        classFunction = new classFunction();
        alert(classFunction.publicVariable);
      }

      function privateFunction() {
        classFunction = new classFunction();
        classFunction.privateMethod();
      }

      function publicFunction() {
        classFunction = new classFunction();
        classFunction.publicMethod();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Private Variable" onclick="privateVariable()" />
    <input type="button" value="Public Variable" onclick="publicvariable()" />
    <input type="button" value="Private Function" onclick="privateFunction()" />
    <input type="button" value="Public Function" onclick="publicFunction()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there are any reason that the new operator will not be working for the second time?

Comment: Take a look at how I do this: http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/CDhFp/1/

Comment: With `classFunction = new classFunction();`you are overriding the global value of `classFunction` so the second time you call that function `classFunction` is  an instance of the original `classFunction`, try using the `var` keyword and use different names like `var someInstance = new classFunction();`.

Comment: And btw, you can't call `.privateMethod` is only declared inside the closure and not available outside it. Try to google about `closure scope javascript` =)

Comment: Hi Prusse,
I've even tried that but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because your variable name and constructor name are same. So, the first time when you create a new instance and assign it to variable, class gets overwritten with instance.

Ensure you name the below differently.

```
var classFunction; 
function classFunction()
```

Comment: Thanks  Ramesh. It was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the constructor function by reusing the name `classFunction` as the variable name.  The norm is JS is to capitalize constructor functions, like this:  `ClassFunction` and that might help.